# get only numbers and letters from list in python

Tags: python

**I have a list as below:**

```
['[',
 'Persuasion',
 'by',
 'Jane',
 'Austen',
 '1818',
 ']',
 'Chapter',
 '1',
 'Sir',
 'Walter',
 'Elliot',
 ',',
 'of',
 'Kellynch',
 'Hall',
 ',',
 'in',
 'Somersetshire',
 ',',
 'was',
 'a',
 'man',
 'who',
 ',']
```

**I need to get only numbers and words as below:**

```
['Persuasion',
 'by',
 'Jane',
 'Austen',
 '1818',
 'Chapter',
 '1',
 'Sir',
 'Walter',
 'Elliot',
 'of',
 'Kellynch',
 'Hall',
 'in',
 'Somersetshire'
 'was',
 'a',
 'man',
 'who']
```

Please help here.

Thanks.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just filter your list using list comprehension and `str.isalnum`:

```
new_l = [x for x in l if x.isalnum()]
```

strings not containing only letters or digits won't match (empty strings won't match either, so that's good too)

result:

```
['Persuasion', 'by', 'Jane', 'Austen', '1818', 'Chapter', '1', 'Sir', 'Walter', 'Elliot', 'of', 'Kellynch', 'Hall', 'in', 'Somersetshire', 'was', 'a', 'man', 'who']
```